# How to change to directory to your homedrive?(C:\, D:\, etc..)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing this batch file which searches for specific a specific file. Now every time the code `cd /D "%HOMEDRIVE%"` is executed, it of course starts to search in that directory. But what I get is file not found.

I tried doing `cd /D "%HOMEDRIVE%` in the command line but it only replies where the cmd is run (e.g `C:\Users\onlYUs`)

How do I fix this? There is an environment variable named `HOMEDRIVE` whose value is `C:`. But it does not change to that directory. And by the way the reason why I needed that because if an instance that your homedrive is set to `D:` or `E:` it can still search for the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change to a directory without providing a path to a directory, and `%HOMEDRIVE%` only contains a drive letter. Without the backslash, it's the equivalent of typing `C:` at the command prompt, which only changes the drive.

You need to add the trailing path separator (backslash) to make it a directory path instead, because you're wanting to change to the root directory of that drive.

This does not work:

```
cd /D %HOMEDRIVE%
```

This does work (note the trailing backslash):

```
cd /D %HOMEDRIVE%\
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is `pushd %HOMEDRIVE%\` which allows the batch to later `popd` back to the drive and directory that were initially current.